# How to capture network packages on Android phones

Tags: android, networking, package, capture

I want to capture network packages on android phones.At first i choose tcpdump to achieve this function,and it did on HTC phones because HTC contains tcpdump under system folder. But when i install on the Samsung phones,the function failed, becase Samsung phones don't have tcpdump under system folder. So, can somebody provide some ways to achieve this function by generial ways.(I mean that without building new img to reflash devices)

So, plz help!

Comment: There are numerous security and privacy implications here; are your reasons legitimate? :) I suspect if it's not exposed via the Android API it might be because it's not supposed to be done ;)

Comment: Yes,but my aim is to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use tcpdump on Samsung too, just copy the executable to /data/local/.